Ansible win_package para desinstalar Google Chrome. Falla con rc=19
Muy buenas, maravillosa gente de este foro salvavidas.
Me encuentro desarrollando un playbook en ansible para desinstalar software en sistemas windows. Un poco más abajo pongo el código de mi playbook. El asunto es que, para el caso concreto de Google Chrome, el paso "name: Uninstall program with route", falla con un rc=19. Sin embargo, el software se desinstala perfectamente, pero, aún así, el paso falla con ese código de respuesta. No estoy consiguiendo ver, ni encontrar, por qué se produce esto. ¿alguien sabe decirme y puede ayudarme? ¿alguien sabe qué significa este código?
La versión de ansible que estoy utilizando es un tanto vieja, también así el python de abajo:
ansible 2.9.27
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Oct  6 2023, 09:53:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Es por esto que debo pasarle el path a win_package, pues este es a un .exe y el módulo falla si no se le proporciono.
También, me he dado cuenta, de que es el mismo código de respuesta que cuando hago la desinstalación vía powershel ejecutando:
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $exe -ArgumentList $params -Wait -PassThru
$process.WaitForExit()
$exitCode = $process.ExitCode
Aquí el playbook. Un saludo, muchas gracias.
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    aplication_name: "Google Chrome"
  tasks:
    - name: Bloque de desinstalacion
      block:
        - name: Obtener id y uninstall string por nombre de aplicacion
          ansible.windows.win_powershell:
            script: |
              $package_info = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* , HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
              Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "*{{aplication_name}}*" } | ForEach-Object { "$($_.PSChildName)\n$($_.UninstallString)" }
              
              Write-Output $package_info
          register: package_info

        - name: Extraer product_id y path
          set_fact:
            product_id: "{{ package_info.output[0].split('\\n')[0] }}"
            uninstall_path: "{{ package_info.output[0].split('\\n')[1].split('--')[0] | regex_replace('^\\s+|\\s+$', '') | regex_replace('^\"|\"$', '')  }}"

        - name: Uninstall program with route
          win_package:
            path: '{{uninstall_path}}'
            product_id: "{{product_id}}"
            arguments: '--uninstall --multi-install --system-level --force-uninstall'
            state: absent
          register: status
          ignore_errors: true
        
        - name: "debug uninstall_path"
          debug:
            msg: '{{ uninstall_path }}'
          when: primer_intento_desintalacion.failed

